# Using log4j2 from endorsed dirs

Tags: java, log4j2, jacorb

My example code is as simple as that:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        LOG.info("information log line");
    }
    private final static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Test.class);
}
```

It compiles and runs fine with log4j 2.11.0.

For a project that uses jacORB, I need to put the log4j jar files `log4j-core-2.11.0.jar` and `log4j-api-2.11.0.jar` into a directory that is added to the application via `-Djava.endorsed.dirs=someDir`. So, when I copy the log4j-jars into a subdirectory edDir and run the above example with

```
java -Djava.endorsed.dirs=edDir -Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j.xml Test
```

It terminates with this output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:41)
    at Test.<clinit>(Test.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.LoaderUtil.getClassLoaders(LoaderUtil.java:115)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ProviderUtil.<init>(ProviderUtil.java:66)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ProviderUtil.lazyInit(ProviderUtil.java:146)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ProviderUtil.hasProviders(ProviderUtil.java:130)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:89)
    ... 2 more
```

It used to work with log4j 2.6. The error described above occured after upgrading to log4j 2.11.0.

Am I doing something wrong?
How can I make this work again?

BTW, the JRE is 1.7.

Comment: Are you really using log4j2? It looks like your code is using log4j1. Maybe you're using the [log4j1 bridge](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-1.2-api/index.html)?

Comment: Actually, yes, I was using the log4j1 bridge: `log4j-1.2-api-2.11.0.jar`. Also tried to use plain log4j2 as suggested in the post from @Bob. No effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occured when log4j classes were loaded by the Bootstrap classloader, which is the case when the log4j jar files are found in the endorsed directory (`-Djava.endorsed.dirs=...`). Log4j didn't handle that correctly (see stacktrace in opening post).

The issue has been resolved in log4j 2.11.1.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with the command line parameter
log4j.ignoreTCL=true

This parameter seems to be designed to look for the class on all classloaders.

So something like
java -Djava.endorsed.dirs=edDir -Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j.xml 
-Dlog4j.ignoreTCL=true Test

Answer (score 0):

Just built your project in eclipse using the example above (log4j-core-2.11.0.jar and log4j-api-2.11.0.jar) - you need to change your import statements and change Logger to LogManager:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;



public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LOG.info("information log line");
    }
    // private static final ExtLogger logger = ExtLogger.create(MyService.class);
    private final static Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(Test.class);
}
```